# Alternative to IBM Data Studio

Tags: db2, development-environment, db2-luw, db2-zos, ibm-data-studio

I use IBM Data Studio (4.1.3 and 4.1.4) to develop stored procedures (native) and functions on DB2 Z/OS (V12) and DB2 LUW. Unfortunately Data Studio is slow and keeps crashing.

Do you know valid alternatives that can be used on both Z / OS and LUW systems?

Thanks.

Comment: If IBM Data Studio is crashing then you should apply the latest patch level to Data Studio, which you can download from IBM .Fix central by following the instructions at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fix-packs-ibm-data-studio   , Although many other tools are available for subsets of functionality, there is only one tool that fully exploits all of the Db2-ZOS and Db2-LUW capabilities, and it is IBM data studio, especially if your site uses more advanced features.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I missed the "DS414 PAR2" package even though it doesn't seem to contain any particular performance improvements. I'm going to install.

Comment: The patches (to data studio) are rarely about performance, but are instead about bugfixes, stability, security , new functionality etc.   For best performance, plenty of RAM and fast cores is the best bet.  If there are specific performance problems that are not related to lousy workstation hardware, then open a ticket with IBM support.

Answer (score -1):

The consumer offers software improvement and database administration capabilities. Use the patron to migrate, create, test, deploy, tune, and manipulate databases and database applications. You can use the Data Studio patron to entire the following tasks: Application development.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).